# npm cheerio - add id to list elements

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I have a list like

```
<ul>
  <li>Name1</li>
  <li>Name2 </li>
</ul>
```

Using npm cheerio how do I add each list element text as lowercase id to the element itself?

So the outcome would be

```
<ul>
  <li id="name1">Name1</li>
  <li id="name2">Name2 </li>
</ul>
```

At the moment I'm adding a static id using

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    $ = cheerio.load('<ul><li>Hello world</li></ul>');

$('li').attr('id', 'new-id')

console.log( $.html() )
```

Thanks

Comment: you can generate them on the fly using a loop where the length of the loop will be the number of items in your unordered list using a little javascript

Comment: I'm working on the server side scraping some html generated from md files..

Comment: cheerio has a [each method](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio#each-functionindex-element-) that you can use, and in your callback, you can add the id the using the [.attr()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio#attr-name-value-) with a function that includes the number in the name

Comment: We arrived to the same easy solution at the same time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick..

```
    $('li').each( function(i, elem) {

        $(this).attr('id', $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '') ); 

    })
```